# Fluent NHibernate XML Field

Tags: .net, fluent

Is there a way to map an XML field using Fluent Nhibernate.

If you have an XML field in MSSQL database, how would you Map using Fluent NHibnernate?

Example

```
        Table("Address");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.AddressId).GeneratedBy.HiLo("1000");
        Map(x => x.AddressLine1).Length(100).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.AddressLine2).Length(100).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.AddressLine3).Length(100).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.AddressPerson).Column("PersonId");
        Map(x => x.ReferenceXML)//Map to XML Type in my Domain
```

Comment: could you be a little more specific? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ayende has some sample code that shows how one can use the XML SQL Server type [here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/05/30/NHibernateAndXMLColumnTypes.aspx).
It uses XML-based NH mapping.  To see how to implement IUserType in fluent nHibernate see [this page](http://jagregory.com/writings/fluent-nhibernate-auto-mapping-type-conventions/) or [this page](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Available_conventions) to see how to implement a fluent nh "convention".

Comment: Broken links are frustrating. In the future, please quote the relevant parts in your answer.